# I'm struggling to get the value from a datepicker into a variable

Tags: excel, vba, date, datepicker

I have a tool with Sub that saves and send the workbook. That all works fine but I want to add the date from the datepicker on the front page of the tool to the subject of the email. For this, I need to get that date into a variable as a string.

I've looked up a few methods and pasted a few of them below but nothing is working. Both have been cribbed from other threads where the OP was happy with the result and worked for them, so I'm unsure why it's not working for me.

```
Private Sub testdateGet()

Worksheets("TEST").Range("A7").Value = DTPicker1.Value

End Sub


Public Sub dateGet()

Dim dateVal2 As String

dateVal2 = DTPicker1.Value
Worksheets("TEST").Range("A7").Value = dateVal2

End Sub
```

The first method results in an error 'Run-time error '424' Object required but I'm not sure what that means. The second method runs without error but doesn't paste anything in the designated cell.

Is there a specific place I have to put the code for it to work as intended? Would I be able to set a public variable for it to update, that can then be used in another module?

Comment: *I need to get that date into a variable as a string* - don't do this to yourself. A `Date` is a `Date`, not a `String`.

Comment: Error 424 very likely means your `DTPicker1` object isn't defined. Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, then try Tools > Compile VBAProject. Does it compile? Make sure the `DTPicker` control is accessible.

Comment: Also note - `DTPicker` will not work in 64-bit hosts. You might want to consider using other means to get a `Date` value from the user.

Comment: Hi - I need it as a string as I intend to include it in the subject of an email. The 64-bit thing might screw me over as I'm running a 64-bit machine and most of the business will be soon.

Comment: You don't want a date as a string, full stop - put its string representation in the email body, at the very last second - everything you need to do with a date in code, you want to do it with a `Date`, not a string. Or, enjoy the headaches and pray all your users have identical regional settings.

Comment: Also it's not the bitness of the OS that's relevant, but the bitness of the VBA host application. DTPicker won't work in 64-bit *Office*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have put up a DatePicker similar as stated [here](https://www.fontstuff.com/excel/exltut03.htm).

Open the editor and open the worksheet code (if the datapicker is located on Sheet1 you should open that sheet) and select the datepicker from the object selection menu (it states *(General)* by default).
[image: Selection Datepicker] 
In the drop down menu top right you can select the different actions a user can perform on the datepicker. In this case select *Click*.

Now add some code

```
Private Sub DTPicker1_Click()
    Foo = DTPicker1.Value 
End Sub
```

Every time a click is made on the DatePicker it's value is passed to Foo. You can insert a Cell here or pass it as an argument to another function.

Comment: If the `DTPicker1` control was accessible like this, I doubt OP would be getting error 424.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon If the OP put the code in a module and not on the Sheet, Running the code from the OP would result in a 424 error.

Comment: Without `Option Explicit`, yes - that's exactly what the OP is saying... about the first snippet they're showing.. I'm not clear why they claim the 2nd snippet doesn't throw any errors (maybe the 2nd snippet is in another module than the 1st).

Comment: Thanks to both of you, a version of Jeron's code worked. I wasn't putting it in the control of the DatePicker and wasn't declaring it as Option Explicit. Once I did both those things, I can get it to dump the date into a cell easily. Another quirk of VBA demystified, thanks guys!

Comment: Thanks for the vote, although defining the DTPicker as an object is a _OOP_ aproach, I haven't thought of. I consider the answer provided by @MathieuGuindon a better solution although a bit more complex.

Answer (score 4):

Error 424 is a tell-tale sign that you're not specifying `Option Explicit`, and so the `DTPicker1` identifier is just an undefined `Variant/Empty` - and you can't make a member call against a `Variant/Empty`, *an object is required*.

Where is the `DatePicker` control? On the `TEST` sheet? Get the control from the sheet's `Shapes` collection:

```
Private Property Get DatePickerControl() As DTPicker
    Dim oleObj As OLEObject
    Set oleObj = Worksheets("TEST").Shapes("DTPicker1").OLEObject
    Set DatePickerControl = oleObj.Object
End Property
```

Now you can access it from anywhere in the module:

```
Public Sub DateGet()
    With Worksheets("TEST").Range("A7")
        .Value = DatePickerControl.Value
        .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    End With
End sub
```

Or, if the sheet exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time, get it from the sheet directly:

```
Worksheets("TEST").Range("A7").Value = Sheet1.DTPicker1.Value
```

You can set the sheet's `(Name)` property (here "Sheet1") in the *properties* toolwindow (F4); that makes the name identifier accessible (from anywhere in the VBA project) to refer to that particular sheet.