# Find date from DateTimePicker in sheet

Tags: excel, vba, datetimepicker

I am writing VBA code for a UserForm. The UserForm has a Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0.

In spreadsheet column A, I have listed dates. The code is supposed to find the row of the date which I choose in the DTPicker.

When I try the `Cells.Find` function with today's date, it works.

```vb
Dim input_row As Long

input_row = Cells.Find(Date).Row
```

However, using

```
Dim input_row As Long

input_row = Cells.Find(DTPicker1.Value).Row
```

yields

> error 91: object variable or with-block-variable not set

(translated this into English).

I tried formatting `DTPicker1.Value` with `CDate` and `CDbl`.

Comment: Is `DTPicker1` a control that you put on your form? Are you using `Option Explicit` ?

Comment: Yes, DTPicker1 is Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0.. No, I am not using Option Explicit

Comment: Here is some reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976950/im-struggling-to-get-the-value-from-a-datepicker-into-a-variable

Comment: You should also be aware that the date picker control is not supported in 64 bit, so if that matters to you, expect more problems.

Comment: Please, try inserting a line in your code and write `Debug.print TypeName (DTPicker1.Value):Stop`. What does it return in `Immediate Window` when code stops on this line?

Comment: @FaneDuru it says "Date"

Comment: @braX I am using a 32 bit Excel.

Comment: @braX Thank you for the reading material. I used the suggestion to modify DTPicker from CallBack to Click - everything works now. Unbelievable.